# CNAME redirect and lets encrypt for traefik

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, lets-encrypt, traefik

I have set up docker swarm with traefik. It is working well.

My DNS setup is like this

`A - prod.example.com - myip`

`CNAME - *.prod.example.com - prod.example.com`

`A - realname.example.com - myip`

and in `traefik.toml` I have entries for several domains

```

```
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "prod.example.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "one.prod.creatomus.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "two.prod.creatomus.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "realname.creatomus.com"
```

```

and in frontend they are defined as 
all three domains work fine and point to the same frontend

`traefik.frontend.rule=Host:one.prod.example.com, two.prod.example.com, realname.example.com`

All the domains work and are redirected from 80 to 443. but somehow letsencrypt certs are fetched only for wildcard domains under `*.prod.example.com`.

Is it possible to use custom domain this way?

How else can I achieve letsencrypt certs for the domain `realname.example.com` if I can't attach wildcard CNAME to the top domain?

p.s. CNAME instead of A pointer also was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing debug mode I noticed that lets encrypt ratelimit had kicked in. Probably I had missed it previously, as nothing else I changed could have made any impact. Now it is all working with the setup described above. `[[acme.domains]]` is not even required, as all the domains are picked up from frontend rules.